# Incorrect response from an MVC app via an angular http post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, iis

I have an application using angular running under IIS on Windows Server 2008 R2 with an asp.net MVC backend.

If an error occurs on the server, to return the error data I do the following:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;  
return Json(response);
```

The effect is that a JSON package is sent back to the angular caller, and  the error handler was called receiving the JSON package

> this.http.post(workUrl, selezione)
>       .success((data: SettoriProgettoResponse, status) => {
>          deferred.resolve(data);
>       }).error((error: string[]) => {
>          deferred.reject(error);
>   });

For some reason, the past few days IIS stopped sending back JSON, and instead is sending the standard IIS error page.

How can I restore the previous behavior?

Comment: could you add your code..how you are doing post call

Comment: I just added the complete client side code, server side I set the status code and return the json payload, client side the .error was invoked receiving correctly the json payload. Now I receive the html of the IIS error page

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem here.

https://serverfault.com/questions/123729/iis-is-overriding-my-response-content-if-i-manually-set-the-response-statuscode

adding this to the web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
    .... snipped other IIS relevant elements ... 
</system.webServer>
```

the procedure restarted to work as expected.
Honestly I don't understand why so far worked fine without this settings, but now seems ok.